# Disks not appearing in Debian installer?

Tags: debian, partition, hard-disk, debian-installer, partition-table

I'm working with the latest Debian Stretch netboot. 
No disks appear in the partition manager. If I go into tty2 and run `lspci` (`lsblk` is not available in the Debian installer), the disk doesn't appear at all. The disk appears in BIOS and is bootable, it simply isn't recognized by the Debian installer.

Of the three identical machines I've tried this on, one produced a bootable install the first time - but when I tried again *without changing anything*, it presented this problem. The other two never made it that far.

What is causing this, and how do I fix it?

Comment: `df` shows disks that are already mounted... you want `lsblk` to see what disks are available.

Comment: Are these three identical machines? If not, how are they different?
Please follow the instructions at https://www.debian.org/releases/testing/amd64/ch05s04.html.en#problem-report and submit a bug report against the *installation-report* virtual package. The `hardware-summay` (mainly the `lspci -knn` output) and `syslog` are probably both needed to diagnose your problem.

Comment: In my case my emmc was not inserted properly. but still selecting detect didn't help. But rebooting the device helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. For whatever reason the Stretch installer (or my preseed, but I haven't changed anything regarding disks or partitioning from my Jessie preseed, which does not have this problem) is skipping the "Detect Disks" step, so of course none show up for partitioning.

When the partitioner comes up with no disks, press `TAB` to select "Go Back", then select the "Detect Disks" step. It will then detect the disk and allow you to partition as normal.